# Enabling/Disabling Forms using Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to Enable/Disable buttons using Database.
[Account Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulo8E.jpg)

Since there will be many types of account for buttons to be Enabled/Disabled, thus controlling such kind of activity via code will require too much LOC(line of codes).
Is there any short method by which I can Enable/Disable buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other solution yet. Let me explain my question with the previous method I'm using for such kind of activities, and maybe as Answer if didn't got another method or solution.

First of all have a look at the Image below(or in the Link).
[This is the Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErSV9.jpg)

1. This is Main form to which Users login using their ID & Pass. All Users would have User Account Type e.g. Admin & User etc.
2. Now Some users(having Priorities) may create a new type of User Account Type when needed and save that to DB, to Enable or Disable activities for this type of Users e.g. He want a type of users not to do deletions. So he Disable Deletions (Forms/Buttons/Tabs[These are back-end processes. What ever you have used will be Disabled for this user.])
3. In form 2 I'm Disabling Tabs.
4. In form 3 I'm Disabling Buttons.

For Such purposes I use classes and call them from Main while loading to Enable/Disable what I want to. Have a look at the code beneath.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class User_Types
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Try;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim a, b, c, d, e As Boolean

Public Sub UTypes()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from User_Account_Types where AT_Name = '" & Main.UsrAcnType & "'", con)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    If dr.Read() Then
        a = dr.Item("Val1")
        b = dr.Item("Val2")
        c = dr.Item("Val3")
        d = dr.Item("Val4")
        e = dr.Item("Val5")
    End If
    If a = True Then Form3.Btn_add.Enabled = False Else Form3.Btn_add.Enabled = True

    If b = True Then Form3.Btn_update.Enabled = False Else Form3.Btn_update.Enabled = True

    If c = True Then Form3.Btn_delete.Enabled = False Else Form3.Btn_delete.Enabled = True

    If d = True Then Form2.TC.TabPages(0).Enabled = False Else Form2.TC.TabPages(0).Enabled = True

    If e = True Then Form2.TC.TabPages(1).Enabled = False Else Form2.TC.TabPages(1).Enabled = True

End Sub
End Class
```

This is old method which you can see require lot of Programming. I needed simple method to do handle such activity.

Hope This may help alot new users but I want to apply something new short and intresting.

Here take a look at this Gif Image which would be the output, I showed the method directly without involving DB. If one want to use DB then he/she can use the upper method.
[The Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRLl5.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Shortest solution for disabling all buttons on the current form:

```
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is Button Then c.Enabled = False
    Next
```

Comment: what if the buttons are with different names and on different forms?

Comment: You need to add a condition to set the enable property to False or True

Comment: This code checks if the control is a button. The name of  hte button doesn't matter. If you wish, you can do this on other forms, too:

Comment: Let say that a user has created new user account type and store that in database.

Comment: Use a panel for the buttons that should be disabled and then: For Each c As Control in Panel1.Controls

Comment: Let say that a user has created new user account type and store that in database. When main form is opened it looks for logged user's account type and gets values of those check boxes where it is true from Database and then disable those buttons which might be in form 2 or form 3 or else where. How would I handle such kind of scenario?

Comment: Useful tip to put all that into one. `For Each c In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()`. Now you don't have to check the type.

Comment: I won't be using any controls, because I'll be comparing all things in main form load function to Enable/Disable the buttons thus this method isn't helping me. Here's a sample. In main form load I want to write code like. After getting values of checkboxes from Database "If checkbox1.checked = true then Form1.Button1.Enabled = False" "If checkbox2.checked = true then Form1.Button2.Enabled = False" "If checkbox3.checked = true then Form2.Button1.Enabled = False" and so on. This is what I need to do in an easy way because I have too much buttons to Enable/Disable while loading Main Form.